# Boost Library function to convert JSON formatted property tree to a dot seperated string?

Tags: c++, json, boost

write_json() function gives me the below .

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "2":
        {
            "3":
            {
                "4": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is also one for the xml format name write_xml

I would like to know if there is a function that can give me something like this

```
1.2.3.4 = test
```

Comment: Please stop putting tags into headlines.

Comment: What kind of "JSON" is this?!

Comment: Maybe you meant `{"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":""}}}}`?

Comment: This question reads almost like an advertisement for the boost property tree library, especially considering the format you originally posted the data in (which reads like the boost property tree INFO format).  Is there some reason that library doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: I have modified the question clearly now .. really apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a function in the library.

Comment: yep , so I simply used a key value map